Is there a source for there being a Psalm inscribed on King David's shield?
I've been told that the Magen David was found on King David's shield (although sources for that seem scarce).
I recently heard that King David had Psalm 67 inscribed on the back of his shield in the shape of a Menorah.
Has anybody else heard that and is there any source that confirms this tradition?

The Chidah in מדבר קדמות מערכת ד אות כב says:

דוד הע"ה הראהו הקב"ה ברוח הקדש מזמור למנצח בנגינות מזמור שיר אלהים יחננו וכו' כתוב על טס של זהב מופז עשוי בצורת מנורה וכן הראה אותו למשה רבינו ע"ה. והיה דוד הע"ה נושא זה המזמור כתוב ומצוייר וחקוק במגינו בטס של זהב כצורת מנורה כשהיה יוצא למלחמה והיה מכוין סודו והיה נוצח אותם ואויביו נופלים לפניו. קונטרס מנורת זהב כ"י מועתק מכ"י הרב מהר"ר חיים באכנר זלה"ה בעל אור חדש על דיני ברכות והעיד הרב מהר"ח הנז' שהוא העתיקו מכתיבת יד הקדש של הגאון מהרש"ל ז"ל ושם כתוב סודות ונפלאות הרמוזות במזמור הנזכר
"David Hamelech was shown by Hashem through Ruach Hakodesh, psalm 67 which was written on a plate of refined gold, crafted in the shape of a menorah. This was also shown to Moshe Rabbeinu. David Hamelech would carry this Psalm, inscribed and engraved in the shape of a menorah on a golden plate, in his shield when he went out to battle. He would focus on its secret meaning and would defeat his enemies, who would fall before him. This is from מנורת זהב copied from the manuscript of Rabbi Chaim Bachrach author of אור חדש on the laws of blessings. Rabbi Chaim Bachrach testified that he copied it from the Maharshal where secrets and wonders related to the mentioned Psalm are written."

